# How to get rid of the period in an item label

Tags: enumerate, labels

When using enumitem, I want to change the label names as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=\parindent,=itemsep=0pt,label=Part \arabic*.]
  \item\label{part:1} append this;
  \item\label{part:2} advance that;
  \item\label{part:3} advance theother.
\end{enumerate}

Look at  \ref{part:1} where we get the extra period. It's particularly bad if I refer to \ref{part:2}.  This gives me ".." at the end of the sentence.
\end{document}
```

`\ref{part:1}` gives me `Part 1.` where I would like `Part 1`. How can I get rid of the period when I refer to it but keep it when it displayed in the list?

Comment: Add `ref=Part \arabic*` to the options list.

Comment: @AlanMunn Please feel free to delete the question if it's a duplicate. Many apologies.

Comment: @Lembik No, it's not a problem to have duplicates, so the question doesn't need to be deleted, but will be closed and linked to the duplicate.

Comment: @AlanMunn Is it possible to have a period but just not if it is at the end of sentence?  That is to avoid the `..` problem.

Comment: @Lembik I don't think that's very good style. How do you distinguish the period of your label from the end of your sentence when the label is in the middle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`enumitem` also has a `ref` key which is specifically designed for this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=
\parindent,=itemsep=0pt,label=Part \arabic*., ref=Part \arabic*]
  \item\label{part:1} append this;
  \item\label{part:2} advance that;
  \item\label{part:3} advance theother.
\end{enumerate}

Look at  \ref{part:1} where we get the extra period.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]